80's/90's comedy with a student pretending to taste urine
I know this is very little to go on, but the scene stuck out in my mind.
80's or 90's American comedy.  The scene takes place in a high school or college lab.  A teacher wants to embarass a smart-alecky student, so he hands the student (a guy) a jar of urine and tells him to check it and see if he can taste something wrong with it.  Of course, the joke is you're not supposed to actually drink urine, so the guy sticks his finger in the jar and puts it in his mouth.  The teacher laughs and makes a remark about tasting urine, so the student says something like, "Well if you did, you'd know the owner had cancer because of the amount of amonia in this urine.  Was this yours?" or something like that.  The teacher freaks out, tastes the urine and says he didn't detect any ammonia.  The student then says, "If you were paying attention, I stuck this finger in the jar (holds up pointer finger), but I put this finger in my mouth (holds up middle finger).  All students laugh at teacher.
Does this scene sound familiar?  I'm thinking Jeremy Piven was the student, but I'm not 100% positive on that.

The scene described is an old medical school tale that has been cataloged on Snopes.com.
The version you are looking for is from Young Doctors in Love (1982)
From filmsite.com:

Doctor Ludwig: "Here in Pathology, we consult the dead and ask them
  how we may cure the living. Here we interpret the messages the body
  sends us. Messages found in substances the uninformed find disgusting.
  They are not disgusting, they are beautiful. They are the ligature of
  pathology. Doctors, the human being emits, oozes, secretes, excretes,
  salivates, urinates, menstruates, lactates, evacuates, expectorates,
  and ejaculates." (Doctor Floyd Kurtzman (Saul Rubinek): "You left out
  regurgitates") "Don't, don't help me, Kurtzman. Now, there are more
  than twenty vital bodily fluids and I am proud to say that I have
  tasted every one of them. This, uh, urine, for example. What will it
  tell us?" (He dipped his finger in the solution and tasted it.)
  "Definite sugar taste. Now I don't need a battery of tests to tell me
  that the patient has a slight pre-diabetic condition. Doctor, will you
  confirm my findings?" (He forced one of the doctors to take a taste.
  Doctor Simon August (Michael McKean) declared: "No, no sugar.") "No
  sugar taste, the Doctor says. Just my little way of showing you that
  there's something far more important to the pathologist than taste.
  That is the power of observation! If you had been observing, Doctor,
  you would have seen that I put this finger in the urine (He held up
  his middle finger) but I put this finger in my mouth (He held up his
  index finger). Lesson number one, Doctor."
Doctor August: "Yes, but if you had tasted the specimen, Doctor, you would have noticed a dangerously high level of fractoids. This patient has pituitary glombosis."
Doctor Ludwig: "Oh, well, let me see that. (He took a real taste.) Tastes like plain old piss to me, Doctor. Ha, ha, ha. All right with a slight, uh, metallic flavor indicating a high level ofzinc. Doctor, here, you try." (He extended the vial to Dr. Stephanie Brody (Sean Young). Doctor August stopped her from drinking from the
  beaker.)
Doctor August: "Wait, wait, wait, wait, just a minute. I
  didn't really taste the urine. I was just kidding. I did the same
  thing he did. I switched fingers. I thought it was obvious."
Doctor Ludwig: "Can I have a word with you, Doctor? Now listen here. You
  might have made a fool out of some of my colleagues, but you'll have
  to get up early in the morning to put one over on Doctor Oliver
  Wendell Ludwig. Now, you look at this face, what do you see?"
Doctor August: "I see alcohol poisoning and prosiasis in the tertiary stage."
  Doctor Ludwig: "Get out, get out! Out! Out! Out! Out! All of you!"  


Ha!  Yes, this sounds like the scene!  Thanks!

Rock n Roll High School Forever...
Three guys taking a mandatory drug test empty concealed apple juice bottles in to the containers when they turn around...
"HEY!!! This not my pee!"
"Yeah this ain't my pee either."
They proceed to exchange and sniff the bottles and finally drink and gargle the apple juice to the disgust of the 

To the disgust of the WHAT?  I MUST KNOW!  Red Viper!  Come back to us!
